# Como acumular en una variable los valores de un método de una clase que recibe los valores de otro método de otra clase en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con un juego de papel, tijera, lagarto, spock. Creo que funciona más o menos todo, pero me falla lo esencial, no me acumula en la variable "puntosAcumuladosJ1". Os pongo las clases dos clases donde no me realiza lo deseado.

```
package piedrapapel;

public class AnalisisResultados {
       
public static void analisisResultados (int opcionElegidaJugador1, int opcionElegidaJugador2){
      
     
        
    if (opcionElegidaJugador1 == opcionElegidaJugador2){
        System.out.println("Jugada sin puntos ¡¡¡EMPATE!!!");
        Resultados.resultados(0, 0, 0);} 

    else if (opcionElegidaJugador1==1&&(opcionElegidaJugador2==3||opcionElegidaJugador2==4)
        ||opcionElegidaJugador1==2&&(opcionElegidaJugador2==1||opcionElegidaJugador2==5)
        ||opcionElegidaJugador1==3&&(opcionElegidaJugador2==2||opcionElegidaJugador2==4)
        ||opcionElegidaJugador1==4&&(opcionElegidaJugador2==2||opcionElegidaJugador2==5)
        ||opcionElegidaJugador1==5&&(opcionElegidaJugador2==1||opcionElegidaJugador2==3)){
        
        System.out.println("Punto jugador 1");
        Resultados.resultados(1, 0, 0);}
    
    else {System.out.println("Punto jugador 2");
        Resultados.resultados(0, 1, 0);
}
}
}
```

El problema lo tengo en la siguiente clase, ya que si bien en la anterior pasa los parámetros en esta no me los acumula en las variables. (Realmente el empate ni me hace falta lo paso por sea caso, pero los otros si). Mi idea ahí es pones un else también con algún mensaje por consola, pero al no acumularme no me sirve el código. Gracias anticipadas por las respuestas.

```
package piedrapapel;


public class Resultados {

static void resultados (int puntoJugador1, int puntoJugador2, int Empate){
    
   
    int puntosAcumuladosJ1 = puntoJugador1+puntoJugador1;
    int puntosAcumuladosJ2 = puntoJugador2+puntoJugador2;
    
    System.out.println("Puntos acumulados Jugador 1: "+puntosAcumuladosJ1);
    System.out.println("Puntos acumulados Jugador 2: "+puntosAcumuladosJ2);
    
    if (puntosAcumuladosJ1<3&&puntosAcumuladosJ2<3) {
        MenuJugar.menuJugar();
    } 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me supongo que tu el metodo `MenuJugar.menuJugar();` hace una llamada al metodo static `AnalisisResultados.analisisResultados(int a,int b);` que asu vez como lo muestras llama al método static `Resultados.resultados(1, 0, 0)` [**Leer**](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2013/02/java-static.html)

Por que no acumula?

- al tener las variables `puntosAcumuladosJ1` y `puntosAcumuladosJ1` declaradas dentro del método `resultados`esto hace que cada vez que hagas uso de este metodo los valores vuelvan a declararse con el valor por defecto 0
- Si el jugador 1 ganase seria PtjAcumulado = 1 + 1  y para la siguiente vuelta si acumulara seria 2+2 , lo que debes hacer es que el puntaje acumulado sea igual al puntaje ya acumulado + el puntaje del jugador

  ```
  int puntosAcumuladosJ1 = puntoJugador1+puntoJugador1;
  int puntosAcumuladosJ1 = puntosAcumuladosJ1+puntoJugador1;
  ```

Solucion:

```
  public class Resultados {
    
    static int puntosAcumuladosJ1,puntosAcumuladosJ2;
//declara los attributos como parte de la clase
    
    static void resultados (int puntoJugador1, int puntoJugador2, int Empate){
//suma el acumulado + el puntaje        
        puntosAcumuladosJ1 = puntosAcumuladosJ1+puntoJugador1;
        puntosAcumuladosJ2 = puntosAcumuladosJ2+puntoJugador2;  
        
        System.out.println("Puntos acumulados Jugador 1: "+puntosAcumuladosJ1);
        System.out.println("Puntos acumulados Jugador 2: "+puntosAcumuladosJ2);
        
        if (puntosAcumuladosJ1<3&&puntosAcumuladosJ2<3) {
            MenuJugar.menuJugar();
         
        }
    
    } }
```